# Getting the convolution matrix from the convolution kernel

Tags: python, numpy, keras, sparse-matrix, convolution

Given a convolution kernel, is there a standard way (hopefully some built-in function of some library) to get the (sparse) matrix that represents the convolution operation?

Specifically, I have a convolutional Keras layer from (54, 54, 128) to (24, 24, 128) and I want to get the matrix that represents the operation of this layer. Is there a standard way of doing this?

Comment: You should edit your question to make it absolutely clear about what you need, because the words you use make it easy to confuse with other terms.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Which word seems confusing?

Comment: @user76284 Convolution matrix can be interpreted as the convolution kernel, the filters used to perform convolution on an image, but i think the OP wants the matrix that represents the operation from a linear algebra perspective.